# add an applet to a smart card which does not support Java Card technology

Tags: java, applet, apdu

This is the first time I work on a smart card and I am not able to understand perfectly how to use it...

My situation : I have an ACOS5-64 smart card which supports cryptographic functions like RSA signature, SHA256 etc... and I would like to add a Schnorr signature on the card, as an applet for example.
The thing is : all I have is the smart card's reference manual which explains how to use card's functionnality by APDU commands (create files, computes hashes or signatures...) but nothing about programing applets for the smart card.
I know that Java Card allows this kind of thing but **is it possible to add applets to a smart card that does not support Java Card technology** ? (That's the case of mine)

Thank you very much for your consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the smart card must have an operating system that supports injecting and running an applet (GlobalPlatform, for instance).  If the card does not have an operating system that supports the lifecycle of the Java Card applet, it will not work.  Even some cards that *do* have such an operating system can restrict the ability to load new applets.

Comment: So to realy customize a card by adding applets I have to work with Java Card...
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: There are other operating systems that allow you to load a custom application; multos comes to mind.